# Move / clone multiple test cases in soap ui pro

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAP UI PRO 4.6.0. I need to clone / move multiple test cases across test suites. I was able to clone a single test case at a time. Is there any way so that multiple test cases can be moved / cloned?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI out of the box does not offer this functionality.

However, since you are using SoapUI-Pro, you can take advantage of the [Composite Project](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/team-testing-support.html) feature, and then just copy the individual tests in your filesystem. You might also have to adjust the `element.order` file accordingly.